# C concatenate string buffer overflow

Tags: c, string, concatenation, buffer-overflow

my C prog return buffer overflow  , i want  concatenate one string  and  one input string this my code

```
#include "ring.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

RING_FUNC(ring_bingetaccount)
{
       char Address[100] = {0};
    // Check Parameters Count
        if (RING_API_PARACOUNT != 1) {
            RING_API_ERROR(RING_API_MISS1PARA);
            return;
        }
    // Check Parameters Type
        if ( ! RING_API_ISSTRING(1) ) {
            RING_API_ERROR(RING_API_BADPARATYPE);
            return;
        }
        char destination[] = "curl -X GET  https://dex.binance.org/api/v1/account/";
        strcpy(Address,RING_API_GETSTRING(1));
        strcat(destination,Address);
        int status = system(destination);
}
```

if i remove strcat(destination,Address); not  return buffer overflow but  ofcourse not do what  i want , thanks at  all

Comment: `destination` has enough space for exactly just `"curl -X GET  https://dex.binance.org/api/v1/account/"` yet you try to `strcat()` more characters in there. Try `char destination[4200] = "whatever";` for a larger space in the array (that is still unused (but filled with `'\0'`s) as of the initialization).

Answer (score 2):

`strcat(destination,Address);` fails as `destination[]` has no more room to append any characters.

```
    char destination[] = "curl -X GET  https://dex.binance.org/api/v1/account/";
    strcpy(Address,RING_API_GETSTRING(1));
    strcat(destination,Address);  // Fails, unless Address is ""
```

Instead, form a large enough array with a [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) or `malloc()`

```
    const char *curl = "curl -X GET  https://dex.binance.org/api/v1/account/";
    const char *ring = RING_API_GETSTRING(1)
    size_t sz = strlen(curl) + strlen(ring) + 1;
    char destination[sz];
    strcpy(destination, curl);
    strcat(destination, ring);
    int status = system(destination);
```

with `malloc()`

```
    size_t sz = strlen(curl) + strlen(ring) + 1;
    char *destination = malloc(sz);
    if (destination) {
      strcpy(destination, curl);
      strcat(destination, ring);
      int status = system(destination);
      free(destination);
      destination = NULL:
    } else {
      TBD_Handle_OutOfMemory();
    }
```

Comment: thanks at all  so much