# Malloc returning invalid size error when allocating memory

Tags: c, malloc

I have this function for forming a HTTP request string. When running, malloc returns an error:

malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)
Aborted

Below is the function I created, cannot understand why this is returning an error.

```
char* integration_request(char* function, char* lower, char* upper,
        char* segments, char* threads) {

char* start = "GET /integrate/";
char* bs = "/";
char* end = "HTTP/1.1\n\n";
char* request = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(start + 1));
strcpy(request, start);

strcat(request, lower);
strcat(request, bs);

strcat(request, upper);
strcat(request, bs);

strcat(request, segments);
strcat(request, bs);

strcat(request,threads);
strcat(request,bs);

strcat(request,function);
strcat(request, end);

return request;
}
```

Comment: You've got a memory corruption.  Run your code through valgrind, and it will tell you where.  To start you off, you're not allocating enough memory.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(start + 1))` That only allocates enough memory to store the string in `start`. But then you concat in more to the end of the `request` string. So that's a buffer overflow.

Comment: Also `strlen(start + 1)` should presumably be `strlen(start) + 1`.

Comment: Like post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69698420/2410359

Comment: This'd be a nice use for [asprintf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) if you're on a system that provides it.  The whole function can be replaced with basically one line, and no risk of buffer overflows: `if (asprintf(&request, "GET /integrate/%s/%s/%s/%s/ HTTP/1.1\n\n", lower, upper, segments, threads) >= 0) return request; else return NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating too little memory. Try:

```
char* request = malloc(strlen(start) +
                       strllen(lower) +
                       strllen(bs) +
                       strllen(upper) +
                       strllen(bs) +
                       strllen(segments) +
                       strllen(bs) +
                       strllen(threads) +
                       strllen(bs) +
                       strllen(function) +
                       strllen(bs) +
                       1);
```

Notice that `sizeof(char)` is always 1 so you don't need to write that.